# Scrape everything between two unested tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to scrape everything between two unested tags ?

For instance:

```
<h3>Title 1<h3>
<div class="div">
    <span class="span">span1</span>
    <label class="label">label1</label>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <span class="span">span2</span>
</div>
<h3>Title 2<h3>
<div class="div">
    <span class="span">span3</span>
    <label class="label">label2</label>
</div>
<div id="div">
    <span id="span">span4</span>
</div>
```

So I would like to scrape just what is located under **Title 1** until **Title 2**. Is this possible using bs4 ?

Right now I have something like this (problem is it scrape everything since classes are all the same):

```
   for i in soup.findAll("div",{"class":"div"}):
       print(i.span.text)
```

Now I get:

```
span1
span2
span3
span4
```

I'd like to get:

```
span1
span2
```

Comment: Beautiful soup generates a tree structure for you. You can identify those two children between which the context matters for you, and iterate from one to other in parent's children.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is best solution to this problem but you can split your text and scrape only the part that you need.

```
text = """
<h3>Title 1</h3>
<div class="div">
    <span class="span">span1</span>
    <label class="label">label1</label>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <span class="span">span2</span>
</div>
<h3>Title 2</h3>
<div class="div">
    <span class="span">span3</span>
    <label class="label">label2</label>
</div>
<div id="div">
    <span id="span">span4</span>
</div>
"""

sub_text = text.split(soup.find('h3', text="Title 2").string)[0]
```

This will give:

```
'"\n<h3>Title 1</h3>\n<div class="div">\n    <span class="span">span1</span>\n    <label class="label">label1</label>\n</div>\n<div class="div">\n    <span class="span">span2</span>\n</div>\n<h3>'
```

After converting that string into a `bs4` object, you can scrape all you need:

```
scrape_me = BeautifulSoup(sub_text, 'lxml')

for i in scrape_me.findAll("div", class_="div"):
    print(i.span.text)
# -> span1 span2
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is:

1. find the second `class="span"`, then navigate backwards, and [`find_all_previous()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous) `div`.
2. The tags are in backward order, so use the [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function..
3. find the `<span>` tags

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<h3>Title 1<h3>
<div class="div">
    <span class="span">span1</span>
    <label class="label">label1</label>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <span class="span">span2</span>
</div>
<h3>Title 2<h3>
<div class="div">
    <span class="span">span3</span>
    <label class="label">label2</label>
</div>
<div id="div">
    <span id="span">span4</span>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for tag in reversed(
    soup.select_one("div:nth-of-type(2) span.span").find_all_previous("div")
):
    print(tag.find("span").text)
```

Output:

```
span1
span2
```